# help need to write regex in optional condition [Close]

Tags: python, regex

I have a logfile having contains as below

log=

```
       Using data from (yyyy/mm/dd): 2011/8/3
       0 files queued for scanning.
       Warning: E:\test\Händler.pdf File not Found.
       Loading com, please wait. 
       1520 file scanned.
```

I want to write a regex to detect the Warning message because this is optional warning comming sometimes I wrote the basic regext to the data which will coming compulsory.

```
logd = re.compile("Using\sdata\sfrom\s\(yyyy/mm/dd\):\s(? P<Defs_Date>\d{4}/\d+/\d+)[^\w\d] ")
data =  Re.search(logd, log).groupdict()
```

Output will be :

```
{'Defs_Date': '2011/8/3'}
```

Since the warning is optional so how I should handle it. I am not good in writting in regex. And please suggest me any good examples or links to get master in regex.

Comment: Don't make it so complex.  What's wrong with two separate regex and an `if` statement?

Comment: Use a separate regex to match the `Warning: ` lines?

Comment: Whatever you do, use raw strings for regexes. Is the line with the optional warning always two lines down from the "Using data..." line?

Comment: yes that can be done but i thought if their is any way in regax that will avoid me to write regax two time...

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker yes the position of warning is fix.

Comment: @Shashi: "avoid me to write regax two time"?  Why avoid?  If you can't get one to work, why struggle?  Why not write two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle optional parts is to use `regex text (optional part|)`. The part inside parenthesis will match either "optional part" (which can be a regex on its own) or nothing.

Comment: Actually the canonical way to write that is `compulsory(optional)?more`

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me:

```
txt = open("test.txt").read()
print txt

import re
logdate = re.compile("Using.*: (?P<date>\d{4}/\d+/\d+)")
logwarn = re.compile("Warning: (?P<warn>.*)")
dates = re.search(logdate, txt).groupdict()
warns = re.search(logwarn, txt).groupdict()
print dates
print warns
```